# Returning JSON Data to a calling class in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am looking to determine when a data download in another class has finished, and then return the downloaded data to the calling class. I have tried with completion handlers but this only tells me the data is downloaded and they reside in the DataManager class, how do I return to the calling class?

**In FirstViewController.swift:**

```
func download(button: UIButton) {

    DataManager.getJSONData(url, completionHandler:DataManager.resultHandler)

}
```

**In DataManager.swift:**

```
class func getJSONData(urlInput:String, completionHandler: ((NSDictionary!) -> Void)?)
    {

        var url : NSURL! = NSURL(string:urlInput)
        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

        let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil

            let jsonResult: NSDictionary! =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: error) as? NSDictionary!

            // then on complete I call the completionHandler...
            completionHandler?(jsonResult);
        });
        task.resume()
    }

class func resultHandler(jsonResult:NSDictionary!)
    {
        NSLog("Data: %@ \n", jsonResult)

    }
```

How do I return jsonResult to the FirstViewController.swift, or alternatively, inform FirstViewController.swift that the download is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the `resultHandler` is doing much, so rather than:

```
func download(button: UIButton) {
    DataManager.getJSONData(url, completionHandler:DataManager.resultHandler)
}
```

You could do:

```
func download(button: UIButton) {
    DataManager.getJSONData(url) { jsonResult in
        // use jsonResult here
    }
}
```

That way the view controller will be notified when the retrieval is done.

Comment: Perfect. Works exactly as needed!